# What type parameter should I pass to an AjaxFallbackLink in wicket?

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

I've been using `wicket`'s `AjaxFallbackLink` succesfully like this:

```
                AjaxFallbackLink ajaxLink = new AjaxFallbackLink("someID") {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                        //start download...
                    }
                };
```

Now, this works without issues. However, the compiler warns me that:

```
AjaxFallbackLink is a raw type. References to generic type AjaxFallbackLink<T> should be parameterized
```

So what would be the correct type to use when declaring/instantiating an `AjaxFallbackLink` to get rid of that warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type is the type of the component's model. For Link often this is just `<Void>`.